# If an application halts, I would like push notification, no pop-up

Tags: system-error, popup, force-stop

Each time an application halts, a pop-up appears, whose OK button is grayed out for one second. It blocks the screen. **This can be really annoying.**

If there is no possibility to get rid of that popup, and instead simply have a standard notification appear in the notification bar? I see no need to confirm that some app has crashed.

Comment: OK, cleanup done then – good luck! Though I'm afraid there won't be any easy solution (at least none without root access) as AFAIK that behavior is handled by the system, not the app. But I certainly agree in not seeing any need to "confirm" the fact an app had crashed. In such a case, maybe a *dialog* would be preferable ("X has crashed: yes/no") if pressing "no" would keep it from crashing ;)